# Ruby on Rails Simple Forms Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a Ruby and Ruby on Rails beginner, started 2 days ago.
I'm trying to build a basic app for the first time and I get this error when I try to use simple_forms gem.

Before I show you the code I want to specify that if I delete the simple_forms code, it works, it redirects me to /orders/new page and it display the HTML page.

This is my error:
*NoMethodError in Orders#new
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/orders/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:
undefined method `amazonurl' for #*

My code:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :orders

root 'orders#index'

end
```

orders_controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def new
        @order = Order.new
    end

    def create
        @order = Order.new(order_params)
    end

    private
    def order_params
        params.require(:order).permit(:amazonurl, :dname, :daddress, :dphone)
    end
end
```

Migration

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|

      t.string :amazonurl
      t.text :dname
      t.text :daddress
      t.text :dphone

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Form ( _form.html.erb)

```
<%= simple_form_for @order  do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :amazonurl %>
  <%= f.input :dname %>
  <%= f.input :daddress %>
  <%= f.input :dphone %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

And my new.html.erb file

```
<h1>New Order</h1>
  <%= render 'form' %>
```

Thank you very much, I hope we figure it out!

Comment: Silly question - did you run that migration?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes I did: rake db:migrate. What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: Can you give full stack trace mate that will be helpful.

Comment: Your code looks good. I hope you have done `rails g simple_form:install`. From the error, it looks like the gem can't understand where to look for the model. You can validate this if you reorder the inputs. It would show the same error for a different attribute.

Comment: Try a rake db:drop db:migrate

Comment: @arjun - I did installed simple_form and it's still not working. @Nathan Schwarz - I tried the line of code you wrote but it gives me an error: "rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'drop' (see --tasks)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)"... I think I should mention that I am using the cloud IDE Cloud9

Comment: Also, something else that might be important. When I run the rails g simple_form:install command, it returns me this: "Running via Spring preloader in process 17166
SimpleForm 3 supports Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation 5. If you want a configuration that is compatible with one of these frameworks, then please re-run this generator with --bootstrap or --foundation as an option." Is this an error?

Comment: Simple form asking you for Bootstrap/Foundation is not an error. BTW, you mentioned first, it is not working and something about Cloud9, and then, second, something is working. SO what exactly are you stuck at - Gem installation or code debugging?

Answer (score 0):

First try `sudo gem install simple_form`, then `rails g simple_form:install`. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes but it will work only on the local computer which is not resolving the problem

Comment: Did you install  `gem 'simple_form' ` in your gemfile and run `bundle install` ?

Comment: I did sudo gem install simple_form and also rails g simple_form:install and it's still not working. I think I should mention that I am using the cloud IDE Cloud9.

Comment: Also, something else that might be important. When I run the rails g simple_form:install command, it returns me this: "Running via Spring preloader in process 17166
SimpleForm 3 supports Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation 5. If you want a configuration that is compatible with one of these frameworks, then please re-run this generator with --bootstrap or --foundation as an option." Is this an error?

Comment: @АлександрБоровой - My gemfile:`source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
end

`